# Showing an endomorphism is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}$$ and the endomorphism $f_A:M_2(\mathbb R)\longrightarrow M_2(\mathbb R); B\longmapsto AB$. I want to show that $f_A$ is not surjective.

My try: $\ker f_A$ is clearly shown to be containing elements other than the null matrix, so $f_A$ is not injective. Since this is endomorphism in finite dimension then $f_A$ is not injective if and only if $f_A$ is not surjective.

Is there any other way to show that $f_A$ is not surjective?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works (it'd be better to explicitly write down a nonzero element of $\mathrm{ker} \, f_A$). Alternatively, every element of the image satisfies $\det(f_A(B)) = \det(AB) = 0 \cdot \det(B) = 0$. Of course there are matrices with nonzero determinant, and they are therefore not in the image.

Comment: Actually any matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\x&y\end{pmatrix}$$ is in the kernel of $f_A$.

Comment: An other way to say the same thing : $I$ is never reached by $f_A$, else there would exist $B$ such that $AB=I$ but A is clearly not invertible

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I'm not sure I understand. What does $det(f_A(B))=0$ for each $B$ imply?

Comment: @palio: It means that every matrix in the image of $f_A$ has determinant zero. So if a matrix $M$ has nonzero determinant, then it's not in the image of $f_A$. For example $I_2 = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is not in the image of $f_A$.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Thank you i see what you mean now.